# Why onTap function runs without tapping when it have arguments?

Tags: flutter, dart, anonymous-function, gesturedetector, ontap

I am novice in programming.
My question why this function is called without tap when I use arguments?

```
String _gesture = 'No Gesture Detected';
  _printgesture(var gestureName) {
    setState(() {
      _gesture = gestureName;
      print("PRINTGESTURE FUNCTION CALLED");
    });
  }

InkWell(
       onTap: _printgesture('Tap Detected'),
       // onTap: () {
       //   _printgesture('Tap Detected');
       // },
       child: Icon(Icons.dangerous_rounded, size: 300),
),
```

I wrote it inside anonymous function, it worked though, but still I want to understand why it runs automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
onTap: _printgesture('Tap Detected'),
```

to

```
onTap: (){_printgesture('Tap Detected'),}
```

---

As onTap is of type GestureTapCallback function, When using on `onTap: _printgesture('Tap Detected'),` you are directly executing `printgesture('Tap Detected')` without waiting for the tap function to get pressed. So when you change it to `(){_printgesture('Tap Detected')` the function would get called only when tapped.

Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureTapCallback.html

Comment: Yeah. I got it. It works without anonymous function when we don't have arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
       onTap: () => _printgesture('Tap Detected'),
```

Try replacing this with your onTap function

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
onTap: _printgesture('Tap Detected'),
```

you are executing `_printgesture` right away and put the result of that function in the `onTap` parameter, which is `null` by the way, causing that the `onTap` doesn't even work.

I was actually surprised that it would compile at all but that's because you didn't define a return type for `_printgesture`. If you rightfully defined it as `void _printgesture(var gestureName) {` you will see that your code won't even compile.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I will define return type of function.